# JavaScript sort numbers properly?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort groups of 3 numbers, however the JS sort function doesn't seem to sort in a conventional way (It sorts lexicographically apparently). How else can I approach this? I can't think of an alternative that isn't a whole bunch of nested if statements or switches.

My current implementation is:

```
var medianthree = function(param){
    var values = param.split(" ");
    var output = [];
    for(var i = 1; i < (values[0]*3); i+=3){
        var temparr = [];
        temparr.push(values[i], values[i+1], values[i+2]);
        temparr.sort();
        console.log(temparr);
        output.push(temparr[1]);
    }
    output = output.join(" ");
    console.log(output);
}
```

With the input:

```
medianthree("1 8 808 708")
```

Which returns:

```
["708", "8", "808"] //the temparray log - used to check sorting
["8"] //the output - should be 708
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the sort method sorts elements alphabetically 
http://jsfiddle.net/7s5m9/4/

```
 function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
}

var numArray = ["708", "8", "808"];
numArray.sort(sortNumber);
alert(numArray[0] + ',' +  numArray[1] + ',' +  numArray[2] );
```

**Updated with your string numbers**

Comment: It seems to work, in this case what does the sortNumber function do?

Comment: @faby: +1 , this works with OPs code fine: [**http://jsfiddle.net/vVcsf/**](http://jsfiddle.net/vVcsf/)

Comment: It converts the string to numeric form (integers, actually) by using the `parseInt()` function.

Comment: For reference: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) clearly states that you must supply a sorting function if you need anything other than alphanumeric sorting.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand where the "a" and "b" parameters are coming from, and why b is subtracted from a? It does work regardless of if I understand it though, so I marked it as correct.

Comment: @JoeCollins you are passing a function to sort your array. This function is used to compare one item with others. `a` and `b` are `array[i]` and `array[i+1]` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JavaScript are Zero-Based.

With `output.push(temparr[1]);` you push the second element which is 8 here.

So if you want it to return the first value use index 0.

Comment: Yes, because the 0th element is the "number of groups of three", which I use in the for to determine how many times to run :)